# Crystal Reports 9 Counting null values if x, y or z is not selected

Tags: variables, crystal-reports, null

Can anyone help me?

I need to write a formula to check if some of my fields are null, but I'm not sure how to do this.

There are 4 items contained within one field and I need to check to see if they are null / blank and then mark these as 'None'

I've tried the formula below, but now I'm finding that everything is showing as 'None' as it's only checking if they are all filled in.

```
    if {VR_ACCESS_Broker.ACCID} <> 17 and 
{VR_ACCESS_CHB2B.ACCID} <> 11 and 
{VR_ACCESS_Fleet.ACCID} <> 9  and 
{VR_ACCESS_Prefs.ACCID} <> 10 
then 'None'
```

So :-  if ACCID 1 has been selected but ACCIDs 2,3 & 4 haven't then I want to show ACCID 1's name

Else if ACCID 2 has been selected but ACCIDs 1,3 & 4 haven't, then I want to show ACCID 2's name

and so on

i.e. if none of ACCID 1, 2, 3 & 4 have been selected then I want that to show the name as 'None'

Basically, the result I'm getting is :-

```
Quote ID     Result

48088          None
48088          9
48090          10
48090          None
48091          None
48092          None
48094          9
48094          None
```

As you can see in some instances (Quote ID : 48094) there are 2 lines for this quote, whereas what I need the report to state is that, if there are any instances of 9, 10, 11 or 17, then just state 9, 10, 11 or 17, otherwise show 'None'.

So I want my results to look like this:-

```
Quote ID     Result                Removed (example - I don't need to see this)
                                   48088          None
48088          9
48090          10
                                   48090          None
48091          None
48092          None
48094          9
                                   48094          None
```

i.e. :--

Quote ID     Result

```
48088          9
48090          10
48091          None
48092          None
48094          9
```

So that I get 5 quote ID's and can count 2 for 'None', 2 for '9' and 1 for '10'.

Can anyone please help?

Many thanks

Louise

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check `null` then no need to write these many conditions you can just write:

```
if ISNULL({VR_ACCESS_Broker.ACCID})
Then "None"
```

Assuming at any point only item present in the field `{VR_ACCESS_Broker.ACCID}`

```
if {VR_ACCESS_Broker.ACCID} <> 17 OR
{VR_ACCESS_CHB2B.ACCID} <> 11 OR
{VR_ACCESS_Fleet.ACCID} <> 9  OR
{VR_ACCESS_Prefs.ACCID} <> 10 
then 'None'
```

Let me know if this is not your requirement.